# Why is the weight of object is not included as a force pushing an object down in fluid?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics, weight

In fluid mechanism, I have one doubt always,

When calculating the force upon object

They said force pushing object down is

$F=PA$ ($P$=atmosphere pressure, $A$=surafce area of object)

But why don't we add Weight($mg$) of object as a force pushing object down?

[image]

Look in it, answer doesn't add $Mg$ (weight of object ) along with $F_1$

Don't the weight should be add as over all force pushind object downward, in image arrow is also mention ($W$)? So that $F_1+W=F_2$ hence a balance system?

Answer (score 0):

It *is* included.  The last equation

$$
mg = F_2 - F_1 
$$

is algebraically the same as

$$
F_1 + mg = F_2
$$

which has all the down-pointing forces on the left and all the up-pointing forces on the right.  It’s also the same as

$$
F_1 + mg - F_2 = 0 = F_\text{net}
$$

where you add up all three forces, with their appropriate directions, to find the net force.

Comment: True, thank u.... So much for the answer.